# How to change the dependency dynamically in runtime

Tags: java, spring

I'm a spring developer.

During development, there was a need to change the dependency dynamically.

this is Module A is called if module B is faulted.

Since the A and B modules were similar APIs that call different APIs, I created an abstraction with Interface and injected it where it used its dependencies.

The interface and implementation are shown below.

```
public interface BookService {
    <T> Optional <ResponseEntity <T >> findBookListByQuery (BookSearchRequestUriVariables variables, Class <T> clazz);
}
```

```
@ Slf4j
@Service
@Primary
public class KakaoBookService implements BookService {
    @Override
    public <T> Optional <ResponseEntity <T >> findBookListByQuery (BookSearchRequestUriVariables variables, Class <T> clazz) {
        try {
            ResponseEntity <T> exchange = restTemplate.exchange (kakaoProperties.getBookSearchURL (),
                                                               HttpMethod.GET,
                                                               new HttpEntity (httpHeaders),
                                                               clazz,
                                                               variables.getUriVariables ());
            return Optional.ofNullable (exchange);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info ("findBookListByQuery exception: {}", e.getMessage ());
            return Optional.empty ();
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class NaverBookService implements BookService {

@Override
    public <T> Optional <ResponseEntity <T >> findBookListByQuery (BookSearchRequestUriVariables variables, Class <T> clazz) {
        changeKakaoVariablesToNaverVariables (variables);
        return Optional.of (restTemplate.exchange (url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity (httpHeaders), clazz, variables.getUriVariables ()));
    }

    private BookSearchRequestUriVariables changeKakaoVariablesToNaverVariables (BookSearchRequestUriVariables variables) {
        Map <String, String> uriVariables = variables.getUriVariables ();

        uriVariables.put ("page", String.valueOf ((Integer.parseInt (variables.getUriVariables (). get ("page")) * 10) + 1));

        String sort = variables.getUriVariables (). Get ("sort");
        if (sort.equals ("accuracy")) sort = "sim";
        else if (sort.equals ("latest")) sort = "date";
        uriVariables.put ("sort", sort);

        return variables;
    }
}
```

The actual place to use is below. The first thing to do is to call the kakao API. If there is an error, call the Naver API.

```
public BookSearchKakaoResponse findBookListByQuery (BookSearchRequestUriVariables variables) {

        saveToBookHistory (getJwtMember (). getMemberName (), variables.getUriVariables (). get ("query"));
        Optional <ResponseEntity <BookSearchKakaoResponse >> bookListByKakao = kakaoBookService.findBookListByQuery (variables, BookSearchKakaoResponse.class);

        if (! bookListByKakao.isPresent ()) {// call NAVER API
            return naverBookService.findBookListByQuery (...);
        }
        return bookListByKakao.get (). getBody ();
    }
```

I have `kakaoBookService`,  I want to combine and `naverBookService` with `bookService`.

If the module calling the kakao API fails, I want to inject a module calling the naver API into the bookService.

Please tell me what to do.

I thought it would be a good idea to combine them according to the Dependency Inversion Principle and Open Closed Principle.

Please let me know if the direction I'm thinking about is a code design issue.

Thank you.

Comment: If kakao API fails ,you need to call the naver API , if I understand the requirement correctly . Please correct if this is wrong . Why do you want to inject it to the bookService ?  You may achieve this through the Qualifier annotation , inject both the service beans and call the other when the first fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use @Qualifier annotation to achieve the same. When the bean is provided to you , the container would have autowired all the dependencies. You may use the correct service based on the usecase

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@Primary
@Qualifier("kakao")
public class KakaoBookService implements BookService {}


@Service
@Qualifier("naver")
public class NaverBookService implements BookService {}
```

Now autowire both beans to the service that uses it .

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("kakao")
    BookService kakaoBookService;

@Autowired @Qualifier("naver")
    BookService naverBookService;
```

Though it is possible to dynamically obtain the bookService bean from the application context on condition , autowiring the dependencies is a cleaner approach.